# jQuery pull out text inside div but not in p tag

Tags: jquery, variables, get, find

In the below code I would like to put a variable to the text within the `div` but NOT whats inside the `p` tag:

```
 <div class="review-content merchant-review-content">
     I want to grab this text
     <p class="review-rating">
     From a cool person
     - My Date goes here
     -
     A Review
    </p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Additionally I would like to only pull the first 250 characters of it, if thats possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/02/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element.html

Final jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9N8N/3/

Comment: I got it from the tutorial, thank you! `var text = $(".review-content")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();

alert(text);`

Comment: Sorry, my original jsFiddle didn't work - I've updated it now with the 250 character limit too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
$("div.review-content").clone().children('p').remove().end().html().substring(0,250);
```