# content out of div

Tags: html, css

This is how i configured the divs in HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="content"><div id="details-middle" class="box">
..........content.........
</div></div></div>
```

And this the css for the div's

```
#wrapper {
    border-radius: 12px;
font-size:13px;
line-height:140%;
width:1008px;
margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;

}
#content {
margin-left:20px;
width:1008px;
    }
#details-middle
{
float:left;
width:700px;

}
.box {border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-radius:12px;
margin-bottom:7px; 
padding:10px 12px;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Everything is showing out of the div's ..

[image: http://grab.by/cdWa]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are floating `details-middle`, which means non floated elements **will not** make room for it, unless they themselves are floated, or you [clear the float](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

My preferred solution is to give the parent `overflow: hidden;` which will force the parent to make room for its floated children:

```
#content
{
    margin-left:20px;
    width:1008px;
    overflow: hidden; /* change here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're wanting, there isn't a lot of description in regards to your question, but you need:

```
$('#details-middle').text();
```

to gather just the text from that DIV.

If you're not wanting to display children elements of the DIV, then refer to this answer I gave recently - it might be your scenario too:

[jQuery pull out text inside div but not in p tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535674/jquery-pull-out-text-inside-div-but-not-in-p-tag/9535839#9535839)